# How to initialize an event

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have a class with an event like this

```
public class A
{
    public event Func<string, string> Message;

    public void Calling()
    {
        Message("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

If I call the `Calling()` method and no one has subscribed to the `Message` event yet, it is null and throws an exception.

How can I initialize my event?

Comment: `public event Func<string, string> Message = _ => null;`

Comment: More in-depth discussion about events can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3102918/945456) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/786383/945456).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't init your event rather you need to check for null in your Calling method:

```
public void Calling()
{
    if (Message != null)
        Message("Hello World!");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The event *is* initialized. To the value `null`. The fix is to check for null first. The canonical approach looks like this:

```cs
public void Calling()
{
    Func<string, string> handler = Message;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Note the event value is copied to a local before the check. This ensures against concurrent changes to the event between the time it's checked for `null` and the time it's invoked. In many programs, this is not needed (no concurrency) and you can safely just check the event itself directly.

If you are using a version of C# (6.0 or later) that supports the null-conditional operator, the above can be simplified nicely as this:

```cs
public void Calling()
{
    Message?.Invoke("Hello world!");
}
```

The compiler will generate the intermediate copy of the reference for you, check it for `null`, and only call the `Invoke()` method if it's non-null.

Answer (score 3):

Check for `null` before invoking your event in class to see if anyone has subscribed to it or not.

```
public void Calling()
{
    if (Message != null)
        Message("Hello world!");
}
```

See: [Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx)

> Invoking an event:   Once a class has declared an event, it can treat
>   that event just like a field of the indicated delegate type. The field
>   will either be null, if no client has hooked up a delegate to the
>   event, or else it refers to a delegate that should be called when the
>   event is invoked. **Thus, invoking an event is generally done by first
>   checking for null and then calling the event**.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Events are, as you have found, *null* by default, which is why good practice demands that you check them before using them:

```
public void Calling()
{
    if (Message != null)
       Message("Hello World");
}
```

You aren't using the return value there; kind of odd, but perhaps its just because this is an illustration.

You could also initialize it to a blank function in your constructor, but thats just wasted resources:

```
public A()
{
    Message += (s) => { return String.Empty; };
}
```

Now it calls a do-nothing function every time the event is raised, when a simple `null` check solved the problem. Definitely **not** recommended, but it is the only way to "initialize" an event.

Answer (score 1):

Although, this isn't your question, I'm going to throw this in there. You can check to see if anyone is listening to the event by "null-checking" it. This ensures that it's not going to execute the method (and subsequently throw a NullReferenceException).

```
public void Calling()
{
  if (Message != null)
    Message("Hello World"); // Why are you ignoring the return value?
}
```

As for your actual question, something has to have a reference to an object of type `A` (as defined in your example.

```
public class B
{
  A MyA;

  public B()
  { 
    MyA = new A();
  }
}
```

Then it has to subscribe to the event of Message.

```
public class B()
{
  A MyA;

  public B()
  { 
    MyA = new A();
    MyA.Message += MessageHandler;
  }

  public string MessageHandler(string s)
  {
    // Do other code here and ensure you're returning a string as defined in your Message event.
    return s;
  }
}
```

Note that the `MessageHandler` can be named anything. I just used that for clarity's sake. It can also be anonymous methods or lambdas rather than a named method.